# Detectar estado de conexión a internet (Loader)

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Hice un loader para una página web, todo funciona a la perfección, pero necesito algo adicional para mostrar que ha habido fallo de conexión a internet o conexión de internet lenta.

¿Algún ejemplo de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Quizás te interese esto [Offline.js](https://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

Answer (score 1):

Este es un [ejemplo](https://output.jsbin.com/keqoyon) del plugin que te recomende, y este seria el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ejemplo usando Offline.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/offline-js/themes/offline-theme-chrome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/offline-js/themes/offline-language-spanish.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/offline-js"></script>
  <script src="check-internet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

check-internet.js

```
Offline.options = {
  checkOnLoad: false
};
Offline.on('up', function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Si quieres probar como funciona realmente, desactiva tu conexión a internet y reactivala